# Is it possible to move a division inside another division only using CSS scripting?

Tags: html, css

I am designing my own profile page on forums, but the creator of the website has disabled custom JavaScript support due to abuse, so I am wondering if it is possible to move one div inside another div?

Here's a HTML code example:

```html
<div class="topLeft"> 
  <div class="someDivClasses"></div>
</div>

<div class="topRight"> 
  <div class="toMove"></div>
</div>
```

And the expecting result should look like this:

```
<div class="topLeft"> 
  <div class="someDivClasses"></div>
  <div class="toMove"></div>
</div>

<div class="topRight"></div>
```

From the last HTML code fences, you could clearly see that `<div class="toMove"></div>` has been moved from the division class `topRight` to class `topLeft`.

**As of December 6, I've realized that it is required to use JavaScript to move a division inside a division. (And according to the answer below, it is not possible to perform this action using CSS.)**

Comment: Show us the desired output and should be able to help you.

Comment: With CSS? No, you need javascript. Perhaps you can show us the actual use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know how to do that is by using JavaScript. With CSS only, I think that it's impossible. Manipulating the  DOM isn't a function of CSS.